# Docu sign Demo Application Recipient is not recieving Email

Tags: docusignapi

i Am Using Docu Sign demo Sample. with help of Demo Sample i am Creating an Application and Trying to Send Email to my Recipient but my recipient is not receiving any mail. i checked email credential and firewall all are okay.
But i am getting Success status by .

```
EnvelopeStatus status = client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);               
// If we succeeded, go to the status

if (status.SentSpecified)
{
    AddEnvelopeID(status.EnvelopeID);
    Response.Redirect("GetStatusAndDocs.aspx", false);
}
```

`Status.SentSpecified` is true all time.
 i dont know where is the Problem?
Thanks in Advance to Assist me.

Comment: Is the email getting caught in any spam filtering or security software?  What type of email address are you using, a private one or a public one?  You might want to try testing with a Gmail or Yahoo email address to make sure that's not the issue.

Comment: Ergin, i tried on Gmail and Hotmail also but  my recipient is not receiving any mail. "status.SentSpecified" is true in all time but my receiver not receive any mail.  can you help me. there is no problem of firewall or spam

Comment: In that case you should modify your question and post the code you are using to create the `envelope` object and all the recipients and data that you are adding to it.  There must be something wrong with your code if it's not going to gmail and hotmail accounts either...

Comment: Actually, another thing you can do to help debug this issue is to make the `RequestEnvelope()` call on an envelope where the recipients are not receiving the email(s).  That call will return envelope information and you can check to see what emails and users are set in the envelope.  One last thing I'll mention, you might have email notifications turned off in your settings.  Check `Preferences -> Manage Email Notifications` in the console to confirm...

Comment: Thanks Ergin for quick response, i am not adding any code i downloaded Ms.Net Sample Code from docuSign SDK i am using that code only. i am not using single line from myside.

Comment: Thanks Ergin, its code ,   protected void SendNow(Envelope envelope)
        {
            APIServiceSoapClient client = CreateAPIProxy();
            try
            {               
                EnvelopeStatusstatus=client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);                              
                if (status.SentSpecified)
                {
                    AddEnvelopeID(status.EnvelopeID);
                    Response.Redirect("GetStatusAndDocs.aspx", false);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when DocuSign recipients are not receiving emails it's because one (or more) of the following reasons:

---

1. The email notification is not enabled for the action in question (usually signature request).
2. Security or spam software is catching/filtering the email before it reaches the recipient.
3. You are setting the recipient as an [embedded](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) recipient.
4. An invalid or incorrect email address has been provided in the request.

---

Possible resolutions for each

1. Check email notification preferences by logging into the DocuSign Console and going to `Preferences -> Manage Email Notifications`.
2. Check your security software settings, firewalls, spam/junk mail filtering, inspect logs, etc.
3. Embedded recipients by default do not receive an email (since they are immediately signing).  Making a recipient Embedded means setting the `clientUserId` property for them.  To NOT make them an embedded recipient do NOT set the `clientUserId` property (don't include it in the request at all)
4. Ensure the intended email addresses are being set.

---

Something else that might help debug these types of issues - you can always request the problematic envelope through an API call and inspect it.  If using the DocuSign SOAP API you can do this through the `RequestEnvelope()` call, if using REST look to do a `GET` call on the `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}` URI

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to what @Ergin mentioned that **there are Features to enable sending of emails to Embedded receipients**.

You should look for these two somewhat confusingly named features:

- Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers *(checked by default)*
- Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers

The fix for me was to uncheck the first one and check the second one.  [This page](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-admin-guide/account-admin/sending-and-signing-options) has a more thorough description:

> **Suppress Email to Embedded Signers (Check box)** – When selected an email completion notice is not sent to embedded signers when envelope signing is completed. This option is only used with the embedded signing function of the DocuSign API and cannot be selected if the Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers option is selected.
>
> **Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers (Check box)** - When selected an email completion notice is sent to embedded signers when envelope signing is completed. This option is only used with the embedded signing function of the DocuSign API.

As a note you will need to modify this under the DocuSign Admin portal's "Signing Settings".